# recaptcha words in other language

Tags: recaptcha

Is there any way to set recaptcha to display challenge words in other language?  I know there is a property "lang" but it localizes UI not words.

I have website in other language and it doesn't make sense having recaptcha words in english because user may not have those characters in their keyboard. for example, if my website is in Russian language, i would like recaptcha words to show up in Russian language not in english.

any help/suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that reCaptcha is actually part of a project for digitising books. According to Wikipedia, they're currently digitising the New York Times archive and some Google Books.

Until they start digitising Russian books, I think you're out of luck with reCaptcha.

Comment: ohh damn!!! I don't understand why do they have feature to localize UI.  only i18n UI feature is not enough.

Comment: I suppose it's because you need to understand the rest of the UI, whereas you only need to recognise (and be able to type) the CAPTCHA content, itself. Why not have a go at designing a new CAPTCHA that's not based on words and take the world by storm? I'll use it when you do ;-)